# Selecting first Class and changing attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have to find a way of hiding a div, I can't edit the html code but I can add a script that can alter it. I have looked all over and I have found that with JQuery I can select the first appearance of a class and get the value of it, but I can't seem to find a way of adding an attribute to hide it. The following is a simplified example of what I need to do.

```
   <body>
        <div class="formbox closed">
            <div class="buttonbar">
                <div class="toc_checkbox toc_email_optin" >
                    <input type="checkbox" name="booking.email_optin" id="email_optin" value="1">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttonbar">
                <div class="toc_checkbox toc_email_optin" >

                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
            $( "#buttonbar:first" ).css("visibility", "hidden");
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**class="buttonbar"** is a class  , so use **dot** for class selector

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".buttonbar:first" ).css("visibility", "hidden");
        ^-- remove # and add .
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bala, I missed it, but it's still not working. It still just not hidden.

Comment: use document ready handler https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: That worked liked a charm, but I did have to add the propper jquery src, the latest version wouldn't work.

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>